# Calling ToList() on Linq Select

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to iterate a collection call the `TransformCvlValue` for each record.

```
fields?.Select(x => TransformCvlValue(x, cvl)).ToList();
```

If I call `.ToList()` it works as expected. 
Why does `.ToList()` need to be called?

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: .Select by itself is just a query definition. It isn't evaluated until you run it. ToList(), along with other methods, will actually cause it to run. You could also see it run by a simple foreach loop. For more information, search on Linq and deferred execution.

Comment: How do you expect it to work? Can you add the rest of the code?

Comment: ToList() initializes and returns an enumerator (IEnumerable) so that you can iterate through the result set.  Since select could be embedded in other linq statements it doesn't make much since for it to return enumerable list as the default return

Comment: If the `fields` variable is a database query it can't translate `TransformCvlValue` function into SQL. When you call `ToList` the result set is stored in memory, where it no longer needs to convert `TransformCvlValue` to a SQL query.

Comment: @nbokmans That is entirely incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Select()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` does not immediately execute the action but builds a new `IEnumerable<T>` with the specified transform / action.
Generally, LINQ extension methods are only called when `IEnumerable<T>`s are materialized, for example via iterating over them in a `foreach` or by calling `.ToList()`.

`Select()` should mostly be used when you really want to project elements from one type to another, e.g. by applying a projection to an element. It **should not** be used when you want to call a method for every element in an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Probably the most readable straightforward way for me would be to simply iterate over the fields:

```
if (fields != null)
{
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        TransformCvlValue(field, cvl);
    }
}
```

This makes clear what you intend the code to do and is easy to understand when you or your colleagues have to maintain the code in the future.

Comment: But `TransformCvlValue` returns some value, which I suppose OP is interested in? In your example this value is ignored.

Comment: Thank you GeorgDangl I went with your solution. TransformCvlValue was returning value, but I did not actually need that so I changed to void

Comment: Yeah, I did interpret the question that you didn't need the return value, otherwise you would not have encountered that issue;)